# Create a new column using detecting the domain of a url from an existing column

Tags: r

I would like to create new column to the existing dataframe I have which will has as value for every row a specific url. This url exists in every row of the Content column of the following dataframe:

```r
data <- read.table(text='"Content"     "date"     
  1     "a house a home https://example.com"     "12/31/2013"  
  2     "cabin ideas http://example.com/name in the woods"     "5/4/2013"  
  3     "motel is a hotel www.example.com"   "1/4/2013"', header=TRUE)
```

However the problem is that the url contains different version but the domain remain the same. The domain is this example.com. How is it possible to create the new column with urls using only the domain to detect it in every row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.table(text = '"Content"     "date"
  1     "a house a home https://example.com"     "12/31/2013"
  2     "cabin ideas http://example.com/name in the woods"     "5/4/2013"
  3     "motel is a hotel www.example.com"   "1/4/2013"', header = TRUE)

data %>%
  mutate(url = Content %>% str_extract("(www\\.|http[s]?://)[A-z0-9./]*"))
#>                                            Content       date
#> 1               a house a home https://example.com 12/31/2013
#> 2 cabin ideas http://example.com/name in the woods   5/4/2013
#> 3                 motel is a hotel www.example.com   1/4/2013
#>                       url
#> 1     https://example.com
#> 2 http://example.com/name
#> 3         www.example.com
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If this does not work you might expand your regex e.g. `(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])`

Comment: Thank you. It work but one question if there are more link before the specific I want to keep in the real data I have I see that it keeps the first link. First link I mean that if there is a link before the target one

Comment: Do `str_extract_all` to get all occurrences of potebtial multiple URLS in a single string